# mysql: group functions on subqueries with limits

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a group of users who perform tasks on which they are scored.  I'm trying to create a report showing the average of each user's last 50 tasks.

user table: userid, username, usertype
task table: taskid, score, tasktype, userid

If I do:

```
SELECT u.userid, u.username, (SELECT AVG(score)
                            FROM task t
                            WHERE t.userid = u.userid AND t.tasktype = 'task1'
                            ORDER BY t.taskid DESC LIMIT 50) AS avgscore
FROM user u
WHERE u.usertype = 'utype';
```

that doesn't work because it does the limit 50 after it does the average of everything.

What I need is this:

```
SELECT u.userid, u.username, AVG(SELECT t.score
                            FROM task t
                            WHERE t.userid = u.userid AND t.tasktype = 'task1'
                            ORDER BY t.taskid DESC LIMIT 50) AS avgscore
FROM user u
WHERE u.usertype = 'utype';
```

but that is not valid syntax

I've tried sub-sub queries, but can't get it that way either, as I always get a problem with the limit, or a join, or unknown fields when I reference u.userid in the sub-subquery.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Thank you for the edit - I thought I had it like that, but it didn't display that way when I posted - & you beat me to fixing it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery within the subquery:

```
SELECT u.userid, u.username,
       (SELECT AVG(score)
        FROM (select t.*
              from task t
              WHERE t.userid = u.userid AND t.tasktype = 'task1'
              ORDER BY t.taskid DESC
              LIMIT 50
             ) t
       ) AS avgscore
FROM user u
WHERE u.usertype = 'utype';
```

EDIT:

I didn't realize that MySQL would not recognize the `u.userid`.  It should according to ANSI rules for the scoping of table aliases.

You can take a different approach which is find the 50th taskid value, and then take everything above that:

```
select ut.userid, ut.username, avg(t.score)
from (SELECT u.userid, u.username,
             (SELECT substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(taskid order by taskid desc
                                                                 ), ',', 50), ',', -1)
              from task t
              WHERE t.userid = u.userid AND t.tasktype = 'task1'
             ) + 0 as taskid50
      FROM user u
      WHERE u.usertype = 'utype'
     ) ut join
     task t
     on ut.userid = t.userid and
        ut.taskid50 >= t.taskid and t.tasktype = 'task1'
group by ut.userid, ut.username;
```

Comment: I tried that one too, but get "Unknown column 'u.userid' in 'where clause'".  I even tried adding in a second user table at the second level to join through, but then something goes wrong with the limit - I seem to only get 50 scores across all the users when I do that.

Comment: That still doesn't work - now it's taking LIMIT 50 of the MIN, not the MIN of the 50.  Which is basically a circle back to the original problem taking an Average of last 50, not 50 averages.  Maybe this just isn't possible in mysql because it does not recognize the outer alias in a sub-subquery.

Comment: @Inukshuk . . . Duh.  If it doesn't work for `avg()` it's not going to work for `min()`.  I was trying to avoid the formulation I just put in.  But there is a way.  If `taskid` is an integer, then you should put in `+ 1` to convert the string back to an integer.

Comment: I saw it, I read it, I understood it, and then I couldn't figure out why it didn't work.  And then I could.  It needs to be t.taskid >= ut.taskid50 (that one was easy); and also in that join, "ut.userid = t.userid" is missing.  And using CAST() is probably better than the +1.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I tried to make 2 more small edits necessary to make it work, but they haven't gone through yet, so I'll post them here.  The join needs to be t.taskid >= ut.taskid50, and you need to specify a table  for at least userid on both select and group by clauses (ut.userid, ut.username).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT u.userid, u.username, AVG(t.score ) AS avgscore
   FROM user u
   INNER JOIN task t 
   ON t.userid = u.userid
   WHERE u.usertype = 'utype' AND t.tasktype = 'task1'
   GROUP BY u.userid
   ORDER BY t.taskid DESC LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: No, that only returns one userid/username & one avg score.  I need a list of all users, each with their own individual last-50 score.

Comment: That's still returning the average score for all 'task1' type tasks for each user.  The limit 50 is being applied to the number of users to display.